# FLATTEN data from SPLIT without helper columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of strings containing data split by semicolons.

| Example Strings |
| --- |
| game1;video1;photo1 |
| game2;video2; |
| event1;recape1;videoe1;photoe1 |

I would like to convert it into one column containing:

| Example Results |
| --- |
| game1 |
| video1 |
| Photo |
| game2 |
| video2 |
| event1 |
| recape1 |
| videoe1 |
| photoe1 |

I'm thinking of using SPLIT, then FLATTEN, and finally FILTER to remove the empty ones. But that means I have to use up N columns just for the transition.

Is it possible to pack it into one formula so I have one input column and one output column?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user four times.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `flatten(split())` in a `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    flatten(iferror(split(A2:A; ";"))); 
    "where Col1 is not null"; 0 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TOCOL

Google Sheets has now added the [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) function which transforms an array or range into a single column.

Using [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) instead of [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) greatly reduces the length of this formula because it can ignore blanks and errors.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   TOCOL(
      SPLIT(A:A,";"),3))
```

[image]